# Non Focusable ListView?

Tags: android

I have a list of items that my user can select from, but I want them all to be "focused".

At the moment, only the focused item has dark text - the others are all greyed out, but I want them all to be equally visible.  Is that possible? How would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Nvermind - I figured it out. I can use android:textColor and android:textColorHighlight on the each item to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

focused means, a single view have the (input-) or (view-) focus. known by that only one
view can have a focus the same time.

i think you want to color a row?